# Timeout messege in browser

Tags: jsp

iam using JSP to run a background operation which will take more than 5 min. but I am getting Screen time out messege in browser. Anymethod is there to remove the timeout messege?
my code is

```
<%         
 System.out.println("vinoth in Execute jsp PATH="+getServletContext().getRealPath(""));
 PhNo=request.getParameter("phone");        
 Email =request.getParameter("email");  
 result =  AntExceute.antTest(getServletContext().getRealPath(""),PhNo,Email);      
 if(result)
     response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");  
 else
   response.sendRedirect("fail.jsp");  %>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are getting socket timeout message

Comment: no. normal internet explorer cannot display the webpage messege